# Make a carousel stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I have a carousel with three `<section>` elements. Like this:

```
<div role="main" class="main selection-carousel">
    <section>
        <h1>Kies je <span class="right">favoriete</span> Smaak</h1>
        <aside class="aside">
        </aside>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h1>Item 2</h1>
        <aside class="aside">
        </aside>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h1>Item 3</h1>
        <aside class="aside">
        </aside>
    </section>  

    <img src="static/img/bg-selection-carousel.png" width="2610" height="600" alt="" class="carousel-image">    
    <a href="#" title="Ga naar de volgende thee smaak" class="carousel-left">Ga naar de volgende thee smaak</a>
    <a href="#" title="Ga naar de vorige thee smaak" class="carousel-right">Ga naar de vorige thee smaak</a>
</div>
```

When you click on the `<a>` .carousel-left. The `<img>` go -1000 pixels to the left. And the second section is show. When you click on carousel-right. The image go 1000 pixels to right. And the section before is show.

But i have a problem with the carousel buttons. When i am on the first section. Then you can not right-click carousel. How can i make that?

When I am in the first section. Should the carousel right-button hidden. And when I'm in the last section. Left the carousel should be hidden.

Thanks!

This is my javascript:

```
$(function () {  
    var background = $(".carousel-image")
        buttonLeft = $(".carousel-left")
        buttonRight = $(".carousel-right");

    $("section").hide(); 
    $("section:first").show(); 

    buttonLeft.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        background.animate({ left: "-=1000px" }, 1100, "easeOutQuad", function () {
            $("section:visible").hide().next().fadeIn(600); 
        }); 
    }); 

    buttonRight.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        background.animate({ left: "+=1000px" }, 1100, "easeOutQuad", function () {
            $("section:visible").hide().prev().fadeIn(600); 
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a similar carousel here: http://jsbin.com/abape3/14

If you replace the `input`'s in my example with your `section`'s and tweak it slightly you should be able to make it work.